# How to set constraint that not allow a column to be blank if specific column is not blank

Tags: mysql, sql

From my image below, I want to mark that if "BirthDay" is filled then "Age" is required, however if "BirthDay" is blank then "Age" can be blank"
I've tried to set "NOTNULL" for both of them and it's not the right way either.

How to set constraint like this in MySQL? Do I need any trigger ?

[image]

Comment: `NOT NULL` only works on single columns, not pairs of them.  You might have to create separate tables to achieve this behavior.  But, are you certain that you really need this in the first place.

Comment: The age changes as the time passes, so it should be calculated on the fly in a query or a view or generated column, not stored. But in general, you would need a check constraint for this to work and mysql does not support it. You would need a trigger for this to work.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisenThanks, I will keep it in separated tables.

Comment: @Shadow You are right, I just put a bad example, should have use Name with Surname or something instead.